# Can I say "I will knock your door" to point that "I will send you another email again FYI"?

Tags: phrase-usage

As the title points out, I don't want to say "I will send you an e-mail again" to somebody. Instead, I try to rephrase that sentence, so does "knock your door" address the same meaning in an e-mail conversation?

Comment: That depends on the *intellect* of the listener!

Comment: so is there a small possibility in a way? so far I have seen 2 strict no.

Comment: I'd have *certainly* understood that in *that* context. It's a *light talk* to me; just to have fun. However, beware; it is an idiom and it is **not good** if not in between friends for fun!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that does not have the same meaning.

In a professional or respectful setting, a good option would be

> I will get back to you (next week).

The (next week) part is optional.

Just as a fun sidenote, if you're talking to very close friends in a very colloquial setting, you could say "I'll hit you up (later)." This is slang in the United States for texting/calling/communicating with someone later. This definitely shouldn't be used in any sort of setting with coworkers or even family.

Answer (score 5):

No, that would not make sense.

> I will knock (**on**) your door

does't really have any other meaning other than literally **knocking** on someone's door.
**Knock** usually takes a preposition.

I suppose you could use the slang

> I'll come **knocking**

which means **I will come look for you**, but it implies physically going and looking, and it might be a stretch. However, if you still need a phrase that has a **physical contact** connotation, then :

> I'll **be in touch**

is possible, and **by email** can always be added at the end :

> I'll **be in touch** by email.

but that has the quality of **being in contact** in general, not specifically about emails.

Are you asking about **sending an initial email**, a **followup email**, or an **additional email**?
I find the **again** in your question ambiguous

Comment: hi @Peter, this will be a follow-up e-mail, to end the conversation (until next week.).

Comment: Since it sounds like you specifically don't want to mention the word **email**, "I'll **ping** you"" can be used since **pinging** can have a meaning more specific to emailing when used properly

Comment: **Pinging** would not be understood by many. That would be very generational, and casual.